# Facebook - Retrieving recent posts from FB API in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I am working on a script to pull recent Facebook posts/status updates for a specific using the Facebook API.  I downloaded the FB SDK and searched all over the FB developers site, SO, and other places and it seems like the code below should accomplish what I need. However, although I am not getting an error, I am getting a NULL result.

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
));

$fbApiGetPosts = $facebook->api('***My Name***/feed?limit=5');
var_dump($fbApiGetPosts["data"]);
```

I have tried using my two FB accounts,(my personal acct and a test account that I created just for this project) as well as one for my company and each time the response was NULL. When I misspelled the account name or used a name that did not exist I got an error, which seems to suggest the request is going somewhere.

In the code above, I also tried var_dump-ing $fbApiGetPosts and that result was also null

Can anybody see what the missing piece of the puzzle is?

Comment: Where is the login/auth step?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the Facebook SDK, but here is how I retrieve Facebook posts:

```
$appId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX';
$token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$posts = json_decode(
    file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $appId . '/feed?
        access_token=' . $token
    )
);

var_dump($posts->data);
```

Hopefully this helps!

EDIT:
The token is just called an "Access Token". [Here are the instructions for obtaining one](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#generating). You might find the [Access Token Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/) helpful, but it's more for debugging existing tokens then creating new ones.

Comment: What $token` is that?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the PHP SDK :

download link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/

Log your app :

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => 'XXXXX','secret' => 'XXXXX'));
$facebook->setAccessToken('stored access token');
```

then :

```
$fbApiGetPosts = $facebook->api('/me/feed');
print_r($fbApiGetPosts);
```

Here is the Graph doc : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/

and the `/feed` ref : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/